# About Javascript output in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I got the problem that output of  my code is weird.
What I wanna do is to sum up the number.

```
var reserve_num =0
var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
for(var i in sheets){
    var reserve_sheet = sheets[i];
    var num = reserve_sheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
    reserve_num += num;
}


//insert sheet("C6") 確認済
sheet.getRange("C6").setValue(reserve_num);
```

In this code I need calculation of variable 'num' but I got string.

I'd like to know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

If this line:

```
var num = reserve_sheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
```

is returning a number as a string, you can convert the number as string to a number as a number with `Number()`:

```
var num = reserve_sheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
var num = Number(num);
Logger.log('typeof num: ' + typeof num);
```